# how make preg match allow write quotes

Tags: regex

how make preg match allow write quotes here is my code

```
preg_match('#$[a-z0-9]^#i',$text)
```

i want develop this regex to allow to me write " or '

Answer (score 2):

For double quotes, you can just type `"` directly. For single quotes, since you're using them to quote the string, you'll have to use a backslash to escape them, by typing `\'`. (Note that this is just telling PHP to use a single quote in the string. Once it's passed to preg_match, the backslash is gone.)

BTW, your regular expression looks wrong. The `$` should usually be the last character, and `^` should be the first. Unless you're trying to match multiple lines, in which case you need a `m` modifier at the end. For example:

```
preg_match('#$[a-z0-9"\']^#im',$text)
```

Comment: Still wouldn't match anything - after the `$` there can only be a newline character or end of string. He definitely needs to swap both anchors.